# Sharepoint metadata search results not display items

Tags: search, search-results, metadata

I had created a metadata property , it called "Category". When I was searching in the search box with "Category:EE" , I get a results which was a list or library . But I want to receive is a items list. I mean , I could saw the content of the item when I click on the title. So the problem is that the results wasn't I want with items name .

My results:

[image]

I want the results like this :

[image]

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer by myself. This problem is the site be created below the CA site. This way will lead to the search funtion get stop . All the information can not be searched. Change the site to other site , it will be work well.